# How to call a function stored in a map from another function inside the same map

Tags: go

I'm trying to call a function defined inside a map, from another function defined inside the same map. But Go compiler says: **"initialization loop"**. This is the code:

```
package main

import ...

var calls = map[string]func(arg string) (interface[], error) {
    "function1": func(arg string) (interface{}, error) {
         // do stuff
         return res, nil
     },
    "function2": func(arg string) (interface{}, error) {
         res, error := calls["function1"](arg) // HERE IS THE ERROR
         return res, nil
     },
}
```

How can I call other functions from inside the map? **The var calls, is not inside a function**

Comment: You could use regular functions, rather than anonymous functions.

Comment: Assigning `calls["function2"] = func ...` outside the initializer block also seems like it would avoid this particular error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After correcting your code so it can even compile (i.e. replacing `interface[]` with `interface{}`, and remove some undefined variables, etc), the actual error is nothing about an initialization loop. The exact error is (see [playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/zi51Wf-K5-r)) actually:

> ./prog.go:10:25: undefined: calls

(If you actually get an error about an initialization loop instead of this, it probably means the code you pasted is not actually close enough to your actual code, so please update the question with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).)

The solution to this is to define `calls` before defining the function(s) that reference it. This is easily done by pre-defining `calls` as an empty map ([playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/A_eEk2RJIOu)):

```golang
    calls := make(map[string]func(string) (interface{}, error), 0 )
    calls = map[string]func(arg string) (interface{}, error) {
        "function1": func(arg string) (interface{}, error) {
            // do stuff
            return nil, nil
        },
        "function2": func(arg string) (interface{}, error) {
            res, err := calls["function1"](arg) // HERE IS THE ERROR
            return res, err
        },
    }
```

Comment: Then it needs to be. Put it in `init()` if noting else.

Answer (score -1):

that happens because at the scope of the initialization of the map, the 'calls' map was not assigned yet.
you can have it as follows:

```
f1 := func(arg string) (interface{}, error) {
    // do stuff
    return nil, nil
}
var calls = map[string]func(arg string) (interface{}, error) {
    "function1": f1,
    "function2": func(arg string) (interface{}, error) {
        res, error := f1(arg)
        return res, nil
    },
}
```

in this way you don't need to have the 'calls' map in your scope in order to get the 'f1' value

Comment: I dont want to name the functions, the idea is to be named with a uri string

Comment: what do you mean by URI string? can you give example?

Comment: I can later do calls["function1"](arg) in a websocket rpc implementation

Comment: by uri i mean some like "user.one", "user.all", "user.post.one", "user.post.all"

Comment: i still dont see why this solution is not valid, because the name of the function will be only in the context of the initialization, and will not be saved by any means. and the end result will be as you require.

Comment: another option (and better IMHO) is to encapsulate these method inside an object instead of a map. you can use an struct that contains a map of funcs (without any calls between them), and have that struct implement an interface that enables to call, all the funcs or just few of them